# Using a point in the unit with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I would like to represent the unit kgCO2eq. with siunitx, but I have difficulties to create the point.
\SI{123}{\kg CO_2eq.} does not work and I could not find a solution so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you given `\qty{123}{kg\,CO2\,eq}` a try?

Comment: Hello. You should provide a MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We won't make friends within the SI community but I'd just define a separate unit for it.

If you don't want that, you need to protect the `.` from the parser (which gets interpreted as a separation between units). However, you will need to think about your full sentence ending period either way.

As an alternative, there's also `\of` which may be the proper way to specify a pseudo unit like that?

I'd also opt for a little bit spacing between the parts but you can just leave it out, of course, but please only use one of them.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\kgCOeq}  {kg\,CO_2\,eq.}
\DeclareSIUnit{\kgCOeqX} {kgCO_2eq.}
\newcommand*\kgofCO{\kilogram\of{CO\textsubscript{2}eq.}}
\begin{document}
\qty{123}{\kgCOeq} / \qty{123}{kg\,CO_2\,eq{.}}

\qty{123}{\kgofCO}

\qty{123}{\kgCOeqX} / \qty{123}{kgCO_2eq{.}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: `\qty` in an undefined sequence in texlive 2022 for me.

Comment: @anis This is weird, because 2022 should come with a v3 of siunitx where `\qty` is the preferred command. `\SI` is deprecated.

Comment: `\qty` is `siunitx` version 3. You can use `\SI` instead for older versions

Comment: Since a kilogram is the base unit for weight and not the gram, I've changed my answer accordingly and am using `kg` as the base for the CO₂ eq.

Comment: +1 Is \of part of the siunitx package?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, it is, part of the unit macros (sec. 3.5 in the manual). How it works can be changed with the options `qualifier-mode = subscript|bracket|combine|phrase` and `qualifier-phrase`. Of course, we could've just used `\DeclareSIUnit{\kgCOeq}{kg_{CO_2\,eq.}}` as well, I guess …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel you are right. For some reasons, 2019 was targetted